# Displaying Response code Messages in a JSP

Tags: java, html, rest, web-services, jsp

I am calling a service which validates email address. In case of an invalid email address the service returns some messages and I need to display that message in a JSP. In the back end java object I get the messages as part of the service response but what I am stuck with is how to display them in a JSP.

I am assuming that I am in a right direction if not then what is the right way to do this? I am not doing validation in the client side using JS any more then how can I display the messages.

I am using `Jersey` and `Struts2` framework.

Please guide, thanks...

Comment: are u using ajax to call web service?

Comment: No it is Jersey.

Comment: are us using javascript to call web service from UI?

Comment: No I am just getting the form id and go in the struts action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the response message in a model object. Then display in a div with condition.

```
<%
   if(request.getAttribute("error_message") != null)
    {
      <div id='result' ><%=request.getAttribute("error_message")%></div>
    }
%>
```

Comment: Are you doing the if condition the scriplet tag?

Comment: What about the error_message? is it name of the variable that you are getting from the object?

Comment: add that variable in the model object and populate it from the service response.